# datetimepicker and dateFormat: unexpected format

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, date-format, datetimepicker

I would like the date in the following format:

yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss (2013-02-01 12:12:12)

This is how I'm trying:

```
$('#start_date,#end_date, #date').datetimepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss',
        onSelect: function(value){
            alert(value);
        }
});
```

The problem is that onSelect i get: yyyyyyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss (20132013-02-01 12:12:12)

[image]

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
```

Comment: @Toni-Michel-Caubet 'yy' is for the four digit year. Check the API documentation for the format: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate